# ansible_default_ipv4.address to get active nic name

Tags: ansible

I have a server which has docker installed, below give me diff interfaces

```
ip link show | grep state | sed 's/://g' | awk '{print $2}' |grep -v lo
```

I have other nodes with bond0 configured as well

some nodes use  eth & other use eno

I would like to query using ansible & get below detils

1. Name
2. IP ( Primary associated with the hostname )
3. Netmask
4. GW
5. Mac
6. Speed
7. Interface name

I have a code basic one

```
  tasks:
    - name: Find primary nic name
      debug:
        msg: "{{ ansible_default_ipv4.address }}"
    - name: Find primary nic name
      debug:
        msg: "{{ ansible_hostname }}"
    - name: Find primary nic name
      debug:
        msg: "{{ ansible_default_ipv4.macaddress }}"
```

Comment: I am sorry but I don't seem to understand your question. You want to find those values for your server? Or just know the type? Because the `ansible_default_ipv4` gives you a lot of information, and mos of what you mention on your list.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `ip addr show` as the initial command it has all the information.

Here is a little `awk` script to refresh your `awk` skills:

`script.awk`

```
NR%6==1{ # for each 1sth line  of 6
    print "name: "substr($2,1,length($2)-1); # print name in 2nd field
}
NR%6==3{ # for each 3rd line of 6
    split($2, arr, "/"); # split 2nd field by / into arr
    print "ip4: "arr[1]; # print ip first arr element
    print "mask: "arr[2]; # print mask second arr element
}
N%6==5{ # for each 5th line of 6
    split($2, arr, "/"); # split 2nd field by / into arr
    print "ip6: "arr[1]; # print ip6
    print "mask: "arr[2]; # print mask
}
```

running:

```
ip addr show | awk -f script.awk
```

output:

```
name: lo
ip4: 127.0.0.1
mask: 8
name: eno16780032
ip4: 192.168.42.12
mask: 21
```